# Facebook login page renders improperly when zoomed in Firefox

Tags: facebook, firefox, zooming, render

I have reported this to Mozilla in a bug report:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=843767

They said that this is a Facebook problem.

Here is what the log in page looks like on 130% zoom:
https://bug843767.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=716721

I was told that, "It's up to FB to change its code."

Is there anyway that Facebook can fix this?

Comment: Should you ask FB that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but why do you ask this here? Report it to FB here under the category "Facebook Home":
http://www.facebook.com/help/326603310765065/

Comment: To which category would I report it?

Comment: I would probably choose "Facebook Home", but they can always move it to the right category in case they don't think it fits where it was entered.